# How to determine the day of the week by the date?

Tags: php, date

I want to display a week by date:

```
   Mon           Tue           Wed           Thu          Fri
2011-12-12    2011-12-13    2011-12-14    2011-12-15   2011-12-16
```

For example, I have the date 2011-12-14. How do I determine which day of the week it is?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to find which day of the week 2011-12-14 is? Or given that date are you trying to find the date of the Monday of the week in which it falls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [strtotime()](http://docs.php.net/strtotime)'s `this week` selector.

```
<?php
$ts_today = strtotime('2011-12-14');
$ts_firstDayOfWeek = strtotime('this week', $ts_today);

echo 'today: ', date('Y-m-d', $ts_today), "\n";
echo 'week start: ', date('Y-m-d', $ts_firstDayOfWeek), "\n";
```

prints

```
today: 2011-12-14
week start: 2011-12-12
```

Answer (score 0):

`date("l",strtotime("2011-12-14"));`

look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more info

Comment: How does that relate to "How to find monday"?

Comment: @deceze Q: "How do I determine which day of the week it is?" A:see my answer

Comment: Q as interpreted by @bneely. I think the question title is still relevant. And yes, it's a badly formed question to start with. :)

Answer (score 0):

[`date('N')`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) gives you *the day of the week*, from there it's only a little bit of math:

```
$date = '2011-12-14';
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime('-' . (date('N',  $date) - 1) . ' days', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d', $date);
```

Comment: How does that relate to "How do I determine which day of the week it is?"

Comment: I thought the first sentence answers it? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
getdate(time_stamp);
```

you can access the day of the week by using the following.

```
$day = getdate(time_stamp);

echo $day['wday'];
```

note: this will return the day of the week as a number Sunday = 0 - Saturday = 6

more info > http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = '2011/12/14';

$weekday = date('l', strtotime($date));
echo $weekday;
```

print the real day name.

Answer (score -1):

```
string date ("l", strtotime("2011-12-12"));
```